# AzureADB2C AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application

Tags: openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I try to use the Identity Provider **openID connect** for **user flow** in **Azure AD B2C** but I have always this message "**AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application**". Below screenshots of my work

[image]

[image]

[image]
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reply URL in your Application Registration at Azure AD should be

`https://your-B2C-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-B2C-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`

as per step 7 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant#create-an-azure-ad-app).